# How to prevent all activity screen from rotating in android

Tags: android, rotation

I have my application with about 15 activities. Now i know one way of preventing activity from rotation i.e. overriding **onConfigurationChanged()** method and defining it in xml.

Since i have about 15-20 activities overriding each of them is not the best practice I think. So is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Do you want to fix the orientation? As in restrict it to either Portrait or Landscape? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: You can check my answer for further reference.

Comment: but each of the activity u have mentioned in the manifest you have to write it.. Isn't it? So is there any other way than this if any??

Comment: I don't think there could be a workaround, but then, it's just one line inside your activity tag. No offense, but how boring can it be to copy paste the same line in other activity tags? And trust me, performing the same in XML is way better than juggling and wrestling your way out through coding. Furthermore, this is lightweight when compared to code. So, advantages with this rather than a workaround (considering a workaround exists at the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add this in your manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

for each activity you want to limit. Also works for "landscape".

Comment: But what i m saying is u have to write it each <activity> tag.. So is there any other way i m asking.. like writing class ??

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen). This attribute inside the `activity` tag of your manifest file can work wonders if you want to restrict orientation. For further reference, the following is very important:

> Note: When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values, it is
>   considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the
>   activity runs. As such, the value you declare enables filtering by
>   services such as Google Play so your application is available only to
>   devices that support the orientation required by your activities. For
>   example, if you declare either "landscape", "reverseLandscape", or
>   "sensorLandscape", then your application will be available only to
>   devices that support landscape orientation. However, you should also
>   explicitly declare that your application requires either portrait or
>   landscape orientation with the `<uses-feature>` element. For example,
>   `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>`. This
>   is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other
>   services that support it) and the platform itself does not control
>   whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain
>   orientations.

This is the specification provided in the developers' website itself. Hence, if you're limiting your app to perform only on portrait orientation, it is also recommended to use the below tag in your manifest, just before the `activity` tag:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>
```

Comment: adding this line only in manifest will prevent all of my activities to be go into landscape mode even if the screen rotation is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

The manifest entry @Stuart provided is the best option in your specific example.

In general though, to avoid repeating the code for every activity, I would define my own class that extends the Android `Activity` and performs the needed initialization in its `onCreate()`. Then each of my activities would extend my extention, rather than the Android-provided Activity directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest:

```
  <activity  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```